VSCode Ruby Error Invalid argument @ realpath_rec
This is a reopening of half of problem documented in
Problems debugging Ruby in VSCode - debugger not executing AND can not display variables
I went back to the original directory where the problem occurred and deleted some of the files i had used while testing (X.rb and garb.rb) then when went to continue coding found i had the same problem (Invalid argument @ realpath_rec) as previously had and which had disappeared.
So I am unable to debug code within this directory.  What I found and is documented below is that debugger is attempting to files that are no longer in the directory this is during a call to
session.rb line 1784 resolve_path

file.  The files I had named above (X.rb and garb.rb) where being used in call to resolve_path file and not being found was what was blowing up.  I added print statements to session.rb::resolve_path to resolve this being the case.  I then added the two files back in to the directory (X.rb and garb.rb) and I no longer had any problems.
I then added additional print statements within session.rb to wherever resolve_path was called
then I again removed the two files but the problem did no reoccur. Within this directory I now have no problems debugging code.  But I tried another directory which had not been touched in several months and had same problem (Invalid argument @ realpath_rec) but the Debug Console was now not showing other than the error itself so received no output from my print statements.
This also occurred in original directory sporadically so not sure why no printouts or trace.
VSCODE RUBY 'Invalid argument @ realpath_rec' error and wont stop on any breakpoints
To isolate the problem

DEBUGGER: ReaderThreadError: Invalid argument @ realpath_rec - C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/d:

I added the following print statements to debug-192\lib\debug\session.rb
This is the session.rb code starts at line 1789 in session.rb
def resolve_path file
 puts "LINE 1785 METHOD  resolve_path#{file}"
 File.realpath(File.expand_path(file))
rescue Errno::ENOENT
 case file
 when '-e', '-'
   return file
 else

  $LOAD_PATH.each do |lp|
     puts "$LOAD PATH CONTENTS LP #{$LOAD_PATH}"
     puts "FILE PARAMATER IS #{file}"
     libpath = File.join(lp, file)
      puts "FILEPATH = #{libpath}"
      puts "FILE.REALPATH(#{File.realpath(libpath)})"
     return File.realpath(libpath)
   rescue Errno::ENOENT
     puts "IN RESCUE CLAUSE"
     # next
   end
 end

This is the sesion.rb output:
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.

$LOAD PATH CONTENTS LP ["C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib", "C:\\Ruby33-x64\\lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/standardrb-1.0.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/standard-1.33.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/standard-performance-1.5.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/standard-custom-1.0.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubocop-performance-1.22.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubocop-1.59.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/unicode-display_width-2.6.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.13.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubocop-ast-1.32.3/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rexml-3.3.8/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/regexp_parser-2.9.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rainbow-3.1.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/parser-3.3.5.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/parallel-1.26.3/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/open-uri-0.4.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/uri-0.13.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/time-0.4.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/stringio-3.1.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/stringio-3.1.1", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mechanize-2.12.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/webrobots-0.1.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/webrick-1.8.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubyntlm-0.6.5/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.16.7-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/racc-1.8.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/racc-1.8.1", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/nkf-0.2.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/nkf-0.2.0", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/net-http-persistent-4.0.4/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/net-http-digest_auth-1.4.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mime-types-3.6.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mime-types-data-3.2024.1001/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/logger-1.6.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/lint_roller-1.1.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/language_server-protocol-3.17.0.3/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/json-2.7.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/json-2.7.2", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/http-cookie-1.0.7/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/domain_name-0.6.20240107/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/date-3.3.4/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/date-3.3.4", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.16/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/base64-0.2.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ast-2.4.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/addressable-2.8.7/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/public_suffix-6.0.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/x64-ucrt", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.3.0", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.3.0/x64-ucrt", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/x64-mingw-ucrt"]
FILE PARAMATER IS d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\ScrapeWeb\X.rb

FILEPATH = C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\ScrapeWeb\X.rb

Note above is failing on not finding the X.rb file in the current directory because it does not exist but had at some point in past.
["C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1794:in `realpath'",

This is the content of the current directory:
Directory of D:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\ScrapeWeb     
2024-10-13  01:52 PM    <DIR>          .
2024-10-13  12:23 PM    <DIR>          ..
2024-10-12  02:11 PM    <DIR>          .ruby-lsp
2024-10-13  12:53 PM    <DIR>          .vscode
2024-10-13  01:44 PM             2,995 agent.rb
2024-10-07  02:10 PM    <DIR>          Data
2024-10-08  03:21 PM             3,389 Document Problerm.txt
2024-10-12  02:11 PM               461 Gemfile
2024-10-12  02:10 PM             2,581 Gemfile.lock
2024-10-07  02:14 PM    <DIR>          LINKS & DOCS
2024-10-13  01:53 PM             1,646 Main.rb
2024-10-13  02:25 PM            26,747 PROBLEM.txt
2024-07-19  11:53 AM    <DIR>          Web
2024-10-13  01:51 PM                19 XXXXgarb.rb
              7 File(s)         37,838 bytes
          7 Dir(s)  112,408,436,736 bytes free

Note the file X.rb does not exist, also file xxgarb.rb was just added as garb.rb then changed to xxgarb.rb as the first error I had was not finding garb.rb.
I have now added both X.rb and garb.rb and code runs to completion no error (a single print statement in test3.rb). Both these files previously were in this directory but had been removed as cleanup after thinking problem resolved but removing these files is what brought it back.
Complete debug console output below. Note that output to the STDOUT/ERR printed on the TERMINAL.
[experimental]
 `,COMMAND` runs `COMMAND` debug command (ex: `,info`).
 `,help` to list all debug commands.
DEBUGGER: ReaderThreadError: Invalid argument @ realpath_rec - C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/d:
DEBUGGER: Disconnected.
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:88: warning: already initialized constant DEBUGGER__::PresetCommands
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:88: warning: previous definition of PresetCommands was here
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:89: warning: already initialized constant DEBUGGER__::SessionCommand
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:89: warning: previous definition of SessionCommand was here
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1429: warning: already initialized constant DEBUGGER__::Session::BREAK_KEYWORDS
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1429: warning: previous definition of BREAK_KEYWORDS was here
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1868: warning: already initialized constant DEBUGGER__::Session::METHOD_ADDED_TRACKERS
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1868: warning: previous definition of METHOD_ADDED_TRACKERS was here
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:2339: warning: already initialized constant DEBUGGER__::SHORT_INSPECT_LENGTH
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:2339: warning: previous definition of SHORT_INSPECT_LENGTH was here
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
ARRIVED IN SESSION.RB
$LOAD PATH CONTENTS LP ["C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib", "C:\\Ruby33-x64\\lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/standardrb-1.0.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/standard-1.33.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/standard-performance-1.5.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/standard-custom-1.0.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubocop-performance-1.22.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubocop-1.59.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/unicode-display_width-2.6.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.13.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubocop-ast-1.32.3/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rexml-3.3.8/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/regexp_parser-2.9.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rainbow-3.1.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/parser-3.3.5.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/parallel-1.26.3/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/open-uri-0.4.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/uri-0.13.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/time-0.4.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/stringio-3.1.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/stringio-3.1.1", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mechanize-2.12.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/webrobots-0.1.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/webrick-1.8.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rubyntlm-0.6.5/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.16.7-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/racc-1.8.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/racc-1.8.1", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/nkf-0.2.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/nkf-0.2.0", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/net-http-persistent-4.0.4/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/net-http-digest_auth-1.4.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mime-types-3.6.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mime-types-data-3.2024.1001/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/logger-1.6.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/lint_roller-1.1.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/language_server-protocol-3.17.0.3/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/json-2.7.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/json-2.7.2", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/http-cookie-1.0.7/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/domain_name-0.6.20240107/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/date-3.3.4/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/date-3.3.4", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/connection_pool-2.4.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.16/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/base64-0.2.0/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ast-2.4.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/addressable-2.8.7/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/public_suffix-6.0.1/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/x64-ucrt", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.3.0", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.3.0/x64-ucrt", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/x64-mingw-ucrt"]
FILE PARAMATER IS d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\ScrapeWeb\X.rb
FILEPATH = C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\ScrapeWeb\X.rb
["C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1794:in `realpath'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1794:in `block in resolve_path'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1789:in `each'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1789:in `rescue in resolve_path'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1780:in `resolve_path'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1527:in `clear_line_breakpoints'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server_dap.rb:348:in `process_request'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server_dap.rb:298:in `process'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:73:in `block (3 levels) in activate'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:273:in `setup_interrupt'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:71:in `block (2 levels) in activate'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:451:in `block (2 levels) in accept'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/socket.rb:815:in `block (2 levels) in accept_loop'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/socket.rb:812:in `each'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/socket.rb:812:in `block in accept_loop'",
"<internal:kernel>:187:in `loop'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/socket.rb:810:in `accept_loop'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:449:in `block in accept'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/socket.rb:787:in `tcp_server_sockets'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:425:in `accept'",
"C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:49:in `block in activate'"]

To further isolate the problem i added print statement to each point in session.rb that
called
def resolve_path file at line 1784 in session.rb

at this point adding my adding x.rb and garb.rb is what cleared the problem I again removed them but this did not cause problem to reappear. I added and removed several times while closing and opening vscode but could
not make problem reoccur.
After documenting this I tried another project which had not been touched in several months
and it is now failing with same error will attempt to isolate further here but all I am getting in the debug console is the error and none of the output from my print statements (also saw this with original problem but got output often enough to track problem down.
I went on to trouble shooting another failing project untouched in several months
This code is being run from project modules but at line
FILEPATH = C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\ScrapeWeb\X.rb

it is refencing project ScrapeWeb\x.rb
I added  a x.rb file back in to ScrapeWeb directory and now the code runs.
I removed the X.rb from the ScrapeWeb directory and the code no longer runs. Added back in and code again runs.
If I now look at the output from the print lines it still references ScrapeWeb directory but since file is there it does not fail line 1785 method
resolve_pathd:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\ScrapeWeb\X.rb in file.rb

Note before starting above I created a new file so VSCode would have no history of it and copied all the files over
and it ran without problems (i.e. does not reference ScrapeWeb directory). Below is the complete Debug Console for same code file but being executed in the new directory
   ,help` to list all debug commands.
 FROM LINE 1511 file =  C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb
   LINE 1785 METHOD  resolve_pathC:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb
   IN FILE.RB        

I would appear there is some sort of stored file history that is not valid
Ruby REPL: You can run any Ruby expression here.
Note that output to the STDOUT/ERR printed on the TERMINAL.
[experimental]
  `,COMMAND` runs `COMMAND` debug command (ex: `,info`).
  `,help` to list all debug commands.
DEBUGGER: ReaderThreadError: Invalid argument @ realpath_rec - C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/d:
DEBUGGER: Disconnected.
FROM LINE 1511 file =  C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb
LINE 1785 METHOD  resolve_pathC:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb
FROM LINE 1530 file =  d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\file.rb
LINE 1785 METHOD  resolve_pathd:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\file.rb
FROM LINE 1511 file =  d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\file.rb
LINE 1785 METHOD  resolve_pathd:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\file.rb
FROM LINE 1530 file =  d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\m_methods.rb
LINE 1785 METHOD  resolve_pathd:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\m_methods.rb
FROM LINE 1511 file =  d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\m_methods.rb
LINE 1785 METHOD  resolve_pathd:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\m_methods.rb
FROM LINE 1530 file =  d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\X.rb
LINE 1785 METHOD  resolve_pathd:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\X.rb
FROM LINE 1511 file =  d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\X.rb
LINE 1785 METHOD  resolve_pathd:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\Modules\X.rb
FROM LINE 1530 file =  d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\ScrapeWeb\X.rb
LINE 1785 METHOD  resolve_pathd:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\ScrapeWeb\X.rb
$LOAD PATH CONTENTS LP ["C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib", "C:\\Ruby33-x64\\lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/json-2.7.2/lib", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/json-2.7.2", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.3.0/x64-ucrt", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.3.0", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.3.0/x64-ucrt", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/x64-mingw-ucrt"]
FILE PARAMATER IS d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\ScrapeWeb\X.rb
FILEPATH = C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/d:\Code\Ruby\_Projects\_Code_Examples\ScrapeWeb\X.rb
["C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1798:in `realpath'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1798:in `block in resolve_path'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1793:in `each'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1793:in `rescue in resolve_path'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1784:in `resolve_path'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/session.rb:1531:in `clear_line_breakpoints'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server_dap.rb:348:in `process_request'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server_dap.rb:298:in `process'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:73:in `block (3 levels) in activate'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:273:in `setup_interrupt'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:71:in `block (2 levels) in activate'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:451:in `block (2 levels) in accept'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/socket.rb:815:in `block (2 levels) in accept_loop'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/socket.rb:812:in `each'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/socket.rb:812:in `block in accept_loop'",
 "<internal:kernel>:187:in `loop'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/socket.rb:810:in `accept_loop'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:449:in `block in accept'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/socket.rb:787:in `tcp_server_sockets'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:425:in `accept'",
 "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/debug-1.9.2/lib/debug/server.rb:49:in `block in activate'"]


I would appear there is some sort of history that is causing wrong files to be accessed for last example i may have opened ScrapeWeb/x.rb in modules project as a tab.  I say this because when I created a new folder and copied all files over there was no problem with the project in the new folder.  Only solution i can see it to copy all failing project to new folders.

Ok I have attempted to recreate problem without success. Was thinking that I had opened files in VSCode via clicking them in File Explorer which left some history but even debugging a file opened that way caused no later problems.

As far as I am concerned the problem is associated with opening a file from another project in this project then later deleting that file from the other project. The current project keeps track of the file after it is opened to refresh the tabs.
Recreated the problem using one of the previous folders (where I got rid of problem by adding file it back in other project). I then changed the last character of the project folder name and reloaded the project. I no longer had a problem. I then changed the folder name back to its original name and my problem is now back. So still appears to me vscode is holding on to the previously opened files and attempting to reopen them whenever project is loaded.
My solution is create another folder and copy in contents of failing folder ensure your code does not have a problem in new folder then rename it back to the original failing folder name. This works but I had expected it to fail when I changed the name back to failing folder name.
Real solution would be to remove all file history associated with that folder but have no clue where that would be stored.
